# Best way to handle this REST API endpoint error?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-boot

Say I have an endpoint to retrieve company:

`GET /companies/:id`

If I hit `GET /companies/16` and there is no company with ID 16, then this returns a 404 error:

> 'Company does not exist for ID 16.'

What would be the correct response for `GET/companies/16/users` if company 16 doesn't exist? Would I return the same 404 as above or an empty array?

Comment: that depends on your requirements. If you need to throw an exception, you throw an exception, if you need to return an empty List/Array, you return an empty List/Array

Comment: It depends on your business logic as @Stultuske said.

Comment: It's more logic to return a 404 in this case too. Imagine a website page hierarchy where you want to access a page /page. If this page doesn't exist, it's obvious that all the subpaths (/page/subpage) will not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If the company doesn't exist, the users associated to that company don't exist either. So returning `404` is suitable for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This question is entirely subjective and depends on what you're trying to do. 
Generally (IMO), you should only return a 404 error if something that *should* exist, doesn't.

Since you are trying to get a company, it would be a bad UI design to actually direct a user to the URL with the parameters. The proper (again, IMO) REST API architecture would be to separate controllers and mappings based on the object entity (in this case, company), then on your frontend, use AJAX calls (using buttons most likely) and HttpServletResponse to get whatever data you need from the mapping. Then you would display the response on the frontend using the response. If the data exists, you would display the company data, if not, an empty array denoting that the company doesn't exist, and you would display on your frontend appropriately with text saying the search result came up empty.

You need to clarify your question further.

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry my question is not clear enough. It doesn't really have anything to do with UI design, my question was about best REST practices. I see that by default Java Spring will return an empty array, and wonder if this is intended.

It seems strange to return an empty array of users if the company doesn't exist, as this would indicate to me that the company exists but doesn't have any users?

I couldn't find any REST guidelines for handling this case so came here to ask other peoples' opinions on how they would handle this situation